# "Explicit" preventing automatic type conversion?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the explicit keyword in C++ mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)

I do not understand the following. If I have:

```
class Stack{
    explicit Stack(int size);
}
```

without the keyword `explicit` I would be allowed to do:

```
Stack s;
s = 40;
```

Why would I be allowed to do the above if explicit wasn't provided?? Is it because this is stack-allocation (no constructor) and C++ allows anything to be assigned to the variable unless `explicit` is used?

Comment: Use your search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Comment: I wasn't asking what does explicit mean, I was asking why is it possible that s can be assigned to 40...

Answer (score 6):

This line

```
s = 40;
```

is equivalent to

```
s.operator = (40);
```

Which tries to match the default `operator = (const Stack &)`. If the `Stack` constructor is not explicit, then the following conversion is tried and succeeds:

```
s.operator = (Stack(40));
```

If the constructor is `explicit` then this conversion is not tried and the overload resolution fails.

Comment: What is wrong with s.operator = (Stack(40)); ? Isn't that legal and we just want to prevent the number 40 being assigned?

Comment: @user997112: `s.operator = (Stack(40))` is legal, but it is an *explicit* call to the constructor. The point is that this version isn't tryied if the constructor is said to be `explicit`.

Answer (score 1):

hey its pretty simple . 
the explicit key word only stops complier from automatic conversion of any data type to the user defined one.. it is usually used with constructor having single argument .
so in this case u are jus stopping the complier from explicit conversion

```
#include iostream
 using namespace std;
class A
{
   private:
     int x;
   public:
     A(int a):x(a)
      {}
}
 int main()
{
A b=10;   // this syntax can work and it will automatically add this 10 inside the 
          // constructor
return 0;
}
but here

class A
{
   private:
     int x;
   public:
    explicit A(int a):x(a)
      {}
}
 int main()
{
A b=10;   // this syntax will not work here and a syntax error
return 0;
}
```